# Is $\frac{\sin kz}{k}$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ a normal family in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ (in the spherical metric)?

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I think this is not a normal family since $\sin z$ is an entire function with an essential singularity at $\infty$. Hence by Great Picard, $\sin z$ can attain any value near $\infty$ infinitely many times with one possible exception. So I attempted to construct a sequence $f'(kz_0)$ such that it has no limit. Indeed, let $z_0=\pi/4$. Then $f'(kz_0)=\cos(k\pi/4)$ has no limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$. But the original function will tend to $0$ whenever $z$ is real. So the sequence to be constructed cannot be evaluated at real numbers. I know the following result:

[For $f$ entire and $\{f(kz) : k \in \mathbb{C}\}$ a normal family, prove that $f$ is a polynomial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422958/for-f-entire-and-fkz-k-in-mathbbc-a-normal-family-prove-that-f)

But I wounder if there is a way to construct such a sequence explicitly, or if there is a way to show nonboundedness of the following expression

\begin{equation}
\rho(f)=\dfrac{2|f'(z)|}{1+|f(z)|^2}
\end{equation}

at some point $z_0$. Any hint will be appreciated.

EDIT: the reason why this family is not normal is $f_k(z)\rightarrow 0$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f_k(z)\rightarrow \infty$ for some other points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions $f_k(z) = \frac{\sin kz}{k}$ are holomorphic in the unit disk, so that any possible limit of a convergent subsequence is also holomorphic or identically $\infty$.

But $f_k(0) = 0$ and
$$
 |f_k(i/2)| = \frac{|\sinh(k/2)|}{k} \sim \frac{e^{k/2}}{2k} \to \infty
$$
shows that both options are not possible.

You can also show that the spherical metric is not uniformly bounded on compact subsets. For each integer $k$ determine $y_k \in (0, 1)$ such that $\sinh(k y_k) = k$ and set $z_k = i y_k$. Then
$$
 \rho(f_k)(z_k) = \frac{|\cosh(k y_k|}{1 + (|\sinh(k y_k)|/k)^2}
= \frac{\sqrt{1+k^2}}2 \to \infty \, .
$$

Comment: I see. The family $f_k(z)$ tends uniformly to $\infty$ whenever $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @kzkzkzz: That is not correct: $f_k$ is bounded (and converges to zero) on the real axis.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @kzkzkzz: You are welcome. I have added an estimate for the spherical metric.